# Create a Date Object with the year only

Tags: javascript, date

I'm used to create `Date` objects by using the fourth syntax [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);` But lately I tried to set a `Date` object with only a year (as `new Date(2017)`) but as you could expect it was treated as a `value` and considered the year as a number of milliseconds.

Is there any way of still easily use the year as is without changing the syntax and expect a correctly set Date ?

Comment: what date would **you** expect to be set when giving only a year ? And if you do have an expectation, then why not provide the relevant parameters ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two solutions come to my mind:

(1) Set the year argument to `2017` and set the month argument to `0` when constructing the date:

```js
let d = new Date(2017, 0);
console.log(d.toString());
```

The arguments will be treated as local time; month and day of month will be January 1; all time components will be set to 0.

(2) Specify `"2017T00:00"` as the first and only argument when constructing the date:

```js
let d = new Date("2017T00:00");
console.log(d.toString());
```

According to current specs this is a valid format and browsers are supposed to treat it as local time. The behavior is same as that of previous example.

Comment: This seems like the best answer. If you don't get the year in a string value simply use `year.toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing a single parameter (*number* or *string*), then it is taken as per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> **value**
>
> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January 1,
>   1970 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider
>   that most Unix time stamp functions count in seconds).
>
> **dateString**
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
>   recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Also as per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description)

> If at least two arguments are supplied, missing arguments are either
>   set to 1 (if day is missing) or 0 for all others.

You can pass one more parameter as `0` or `null` (or the actual value you want to set)

```
new Date(2017,0);
```

**Demo**

```js
var date = new Date(2017,0);
console.log( date );
```

Comment: This is very likely to fail since in half of the world (timezone related) it will be translated to 2016

Comment: That is true, but given the restrictions OP has put in his question there is not much that can be done about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `null` as second argument:

```
new Date(2017, null);
```

However, without knowing the details of how missing values are interpreted, what do you think happens now? Will the date be initialized with the *current* month, day, hour, etc? Or something different?

**Better be explicit** and pass all arguments, so that you know what the code is doing half a year later.

Comment: As I told @gurvinder372, this will sometimes create a date with the year 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion. You can just create a regular date object and set it's year. So at least you know to expect what the rest of the Date object values are.

```
var year = "2014";

var date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(year);

// console.log(year) => Wed Dec 27 2014 16:25:28 GMT+0200
```

Further reading - [Date.prototype.setFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear)